# Cannot overwrite files in remote server via SFTP in 16.04

Tags: nautilus, 16.04, sftp

I used to connect to sever via nautilus over SFTP in Ubuntu 14.04.

Now I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer. I can create files on remote server, but I cannot overwrite any file. I cannot edit files in gedit too.

It should not be a permission problem, as I connected via root (of remote server). On the other hand, I can create/rename/delete files, but I cannot overwrite or add content.

The problem is not related to the server setting, as I can connect from my computer with Ubuntu 14.04, but not Ubuntu 16.04. Something has been changed in Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution by trial and error. I share it if others face this problem.

You have to install `openssh-server` on client machine too.

I don't know why, and why I did not encountered this problem in previous versions of Ubuntu. Probably `openssh-server` was included in the previous installation of Ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 0):

When youre using `proftpd`on your server you might want to have a look again at the settings you gave to the directory and user created there.

The entry in `/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf`should look like this:

```
<Anonymous /home/username/server>
User username
Group admins
AnonRequirePassword on
MaxClients 10 "The server is full, hosting %m users"
DisplayLogin welcome.msg
DisplayChdir .msg
<Limit LOGIN>
Allow from All
Deny from all
</Limit>
AllowOverwrite on
<Limit LIST NLST  STOR STOU  APPE  RETR  RNFR RNTO  DELE  MKD XMKD SITE_MKDIR  RMD XRMD SITE_RMDIR  SITE  SITE_CHMOD  SITE_CHGRP  MTDM  PWD XPWD  SIZE  STAT  CWD XCWD  CDUP XCUP >
 AllowAll
</Limit>
<Limit NOTHING >
 DenyAll
</Limit>
</Anonymous>
```

**Be warned that this is a kind of allow really all setting, so it is not suited to set for other user accounts.**

Comment: It's not related to the sever setting. I still can connect to the server from my computer with Ubuntu 14.04. I cannot connect from my new computer with Ubuntu 16.04. Anyway, I don't have `proftpd` on my server.